# I dont know whats wrong with my Python code im trying a simple randomiser and its not quite working

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code

```
import time
import attacker
import random

"You sumble of the path and are confronted with "

attaker=random,randint(0,5)

if attacker==1:
    print" Gandalf"
if attaker==2:
    print" Harry Potter"
if attaker==3:
    print" a Smurf"
if attaker==4:
    print" a wierd dude with a sword "
if attaker==5:
    print" a Giant Spider"
```

The Syntax error is "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\V1", line 3, in 
    import attacker
ImportError: No module named attacker"

Answer (score 0):

`import attacker` at the top assumes there's a module attacker.py or attacker.pyc .  Since you use attacker to store a number, I'm guessing there is no module.  Hence the error.

Also `attaker=random,randint(0,5)` should be `attaker=random.randint(0,5)`.  The dot is how you invoke module's variables or functions.